# Postman - Generate Code Snippets - Does not work with C# RestSharp

Tags: postman

I created a PostMan request. Basic 'Posting' of JSON. It works fine in Postman !
When I click on '**Code**' in PostMan and select **Generate Code Snippets** for **C# RestSharp** it generates the following:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://localhost:44331/api/workorder");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", " { \"dataSource\":\"Axw163\",\"Number\":\"3450489\",\"UserId\":\"XXX\",\"Password\":\"XXX\",\"EndPoint\":\"http://MYENDPOINT\",\"App\": \"WORK\"}\r\nstrong text",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

When I paste the code into my app and run it I get the following:

> ```
> {
>     "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
>     "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
>     "status": 400,
>     "traceId": "|49b7f241-4e7e8b1ee8900c92.",
>     "errors": {
>         "$": ["The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."]
>     }
> }
> ```

Any idea why it works in Postman and not in the generated C# code?

HERE's the POSTMAN

```
"id": "a59638d6-4f81-4318-bc55-181a088c00a4",
                    "name": "https://localhost:44331/api/workorder",
                    "url": "https://localhost:44331/api/workorder",
                    "description": "Get Work Order",
                    "data": [],
                    "dataOptions": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "json"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataMode": "raw",
                    "headerData": [
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Type",
                            "name": "Content-Type",
                            "value": "application/json",
                            "description": "",
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    ],
                    "method": "GET",
                    "pathVariableData": [],
                    "queryParams": [],
                    "auth": null,
                    "events": null,
                    "folder": null,
                    "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                        "disableBodyPruning": true
                    },
                    "currentHelper": null,
                    "helperAttributes": null,
                    "collectionId": "64bf01de-822f-41d3-b596-7c351a8665e8",
                    "rawModeData": " { \"dataSource\":\"XXX\",\"Number\":\"3450489\",\"UserId\":\"XXX\",\"Password\":\"XX\",\"EndPoint\":\"http://xxxxxxxxxcloudapp.azure.com/AppXtenderrest\",\"App\": \"WMIS_WORK_REQUEST\"}\r\n            ",
                    "headers": "Content-Type: application/json\n",
                    "pathVariables": {}
```

Comment: Can you post what your request looks like in Postman ?

Comment: I get too long to post